# Rails + globalize - disabling translations autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, globalize

I have an app with these gems:

rails 5.2.8.1

globalize 6.2.1

globalize-accessors 0.3.0

Seems translations are always autoloaded eventhough I'm not calling the accessors/translated columns. For example:

```
Model.where(id:123)
Model Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "model"."id", "model"."column1", "model"."created_at", "model"."updated_at" FROM "model" WHERE "model"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 123], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Model::Translation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "model_translations".* FROM "model_translations" WHERE "model_translations"."model_id" = $1  [["model_id", 123]]
```

why are translations auto loaded? How do I disable this? I also tried:

```
Model.where(id:123).select(:id)
Model Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "model"."id" FROM "model" WHERE "model"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 123], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Model::Translation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "model_translations".* FROM "model_translations" WHERE "model_translations"."model_id" = $1  [["model_id", 123]]
```

Is there a way to prevent calling SELECT on the translations table? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way to prevent the translations from being autoloaded. You can do this by setting the `globalize_load_translations` option to `false` in your model. For example:

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  globalize_load_translations false
end
```

This will prevent the translations from being loaded when you call `Model.find(123)`. However, if you do need to access the translations, you can still do so by calling the translations method on the model instance. For example:

```
model = Model.find(123)
translations = model.translations
```

This will only load the translations if they are actually needed.

You can also disable the translation autoloading globally by setting the `config.globalize.load_translations` option to false in your Rails application configuration file. For example:

```
config.globalize.load_translations = false
```

This will disable the translation autoloading for all models in your application.

Comment: Could you please add link to documentation or source code? I can't find it

Comment: I tried to find, and this is the best documentation I could find: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/globalize/5.0.1

Comment: And where is this `load_translations` there?

Comment: are u sure ?? i just cloned both globalize and globalize_accessors repo and look for the keyword load_translations. there's no results